# Express how many ways you can select a representative

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Assume that a school has these three teams: Chess team with 10 members, Checkers team with 15 members, and College bowl team with 20 members.

In how many ways can we select representatives of the school if there should be:

1. exactly 1 representative from each team.
2. 2 persons, and they should be from different teams.
3. 1, 2, or 3 persons but no two from the same team.
4. 2 persons, both from the same team.
5. 2 persons from any team.

Answers

1. $20*15*10$ using the product rule
2. $10 \cdot 15 + 10 \cdot 20 + 15 \cdot 20$

Comment: For problem 1, your answer "20+15+10" answers the question of "exactly 1 representative *total*."  The question seems to be intended to read as "one representative from *each* team (for a total of 3 people)."  You will use the multiplication principle here, not the summation principle.

Comment: so would it be $20*15*10$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

These will rely on various applications of the multiplication principle, permutations, combinations, and the summation principle.

1: There will be one representative from each team.  Who is the representative from the checkers team?  Who is the representative from the chess team?  Who is the representative from the College bowl team?

2: Consider the set of all 2 person groups with no restriction on what team they come from (same answer as problem 5).  How many of those are "bad" selections such that they came from the same team (same as problem 4)?  Use inclusion-exclusion to find the number of "good" selections.

3: Split this into cases.  If 1 person, choose that one person.  If 2 people, with no two from same team, this is same answer as problem 2.  If 3 people, this is one from each team (same as problem 1).

4: Split this into cases.  If both are from the chess team, which two are they?  If both are from the checkers team, which two are they?  If both are from the college bowl team, which two are they?  Use combinations to answer those questions, and finish by using summation rule.

5: There are no restrictions whatsoever, so 2 people out of the total population.

Comment: Note that selecting three people in part 3, with no two from the same team is just problem 1.

Comment: Good catch.  Much simpler way to describe that scenario.  In my mind I was still in inclusion-exclusion mode.

Comment: Are supposed to subtract the bad selections? If so how do I determine the bad selections?

Comment: @Csci319  In problem 2, a bad selection is one in which both people are selected from the same team.  That means you must subtract the number of ways you could pick two people from the chess team or two people from the checkers team or two people from the college bowl team from the total.  That is, you would subtract your answer for problem 4 from the total number of ways of selecting two of the $10 + 15 + 20$ possible representatives.  However, you could also compute the answer directly using the Multiplication and Addition Principles.

Comment: So to get part to I have to calculate how to choose two people from each team then subtract that from my part 1 answer?

Comment: @Csci319 That is one way.  Alternatively, you could compute the answer directly as follows:  Select one person each from the chess team and checkers team, or one person each from the chess team and college bowl team, or one person each from the checkers team and the college bowl team.

Comment: thanks so much, I just want to make sure I understand each step before I continue. Just to select 2 people from on team all I need to do it $20^2$ $15^2$ or $10^2$?

Comment: @Csci319 The number of ways of selecting two people from the chess team is $\binom{10}{2}$ since you are selecting a subset of two people from a set of ten people.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21151/discussion-between-csci319-and-n-f-taussig).

Comment: @Csci319 I do not see where I am supposed to respond in chat.  What am I looking for?

Comment: @JMoravitz any more input?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig you cannot click on my post above yours?

Comment: @Csci319  Sorry, I had to reload the page in the chat room.  I have answered your question there.

Comment: @Csci319 I had left to go to dinner.  It seems that Taussig successfully answered your remaining questions.  If not, feel free to ping me in chat by using the @ symbol by my name in either the main chat room or the room that was opened for the earlier discussion.